# InDesign Excel Table changes character style after import

Tags: adobe-indesign, import, microsoft-excel

I am using a linked Excel file (xls) in InDesign. I have all of the cells using cell styles that then use a paragraph style, and character style. The cell character style is changing after I update the Excel file.

All text in the tables has a Character Style set to "None". After I update the link for the Excel file. All text in the table then use a character style I have called "Title Text" which has a very large front size. If no character styles get applied after re-importing the Excel file, then I am fine...

How do I can update the linked Excel file without the cell character style changing after import?

[image: Update table cell]

Comment: Is the import set to `Formatted Table` or `Unformatted table`? I suspect one may cause an issue, but I'm really not certain.

Comment: Hard to say from just this screen recording. What does the character styles palette say before and after? Is the reason the cells become overset because the font size has increased massively, or some other reason?

Comment: @MG_ All text in the tables has a Character Style set to "None". After I update the link for the Excel file. All text in the table then use a character style I have called "Title Text" which has a very large front size. If no character styles get applied after re-importing the Excel file, then I am fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table text was changing after re-importing the Excel file because I had a pre-selected Character Style select in the Character Style Window.

To fix this, I opened the InDesign file before I edit the text in Excel. I select nothing and change the Character Style to None. I save and close InDesign. I then edit the info in Excel, close, open the InDesign file with updating links and the text Character Style doesn't change and stays at None.